# Is there a centralised security notifications list for web based apps?

Tags: security

This may be in the wrong stackexchange but I was wondering if there was a centralised mailing list or website that sent out security advisories for different web apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking around a while for a filtered security alert feed for web applications as well, and have found a couple:

- [US-CERT Bulletins](http://www.us-cert.gov/cas/bulletins/) contain some popular web application alerts (drupal, apache, etc...).
         (They also have [other alert mailing lists & feeds here](http://www.us-cert.gov/cas/signup.html))
- [SANS @Risk Security Alert Newsletter](http://www.sans.org/newsletters/risk/) contains a some web application security alerts
         (They also have [other newsletters here](http://www.sans.org/newsletters/))
- [FreeCode Security Articles](http://freecode.com/tags/security/articles) can provide some security alerts
         (Has many open source projects tracked)
- [National Vulnerability Database](http://nvd.nist.gov/download.cfm#RSS) has feeds for vulnerabilities tracked in the CVE database
- [CVE Data Updates and RSS Feeds](http://cve.mitre.org/cve/data_updates.html) has a changelog for all CVE entries, as well as a link to the above NVD feed.

It would be nice to have an easy way to filter these for only the apps I'm interested in supporting and updating, but I just haven't had the time to develop a solution yet.